# iptables - remove packet mark on certain packets

Tags: iptables

I am using the following iptables script to redirect packets on port 443 to a proxy server:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

I am redirecting it to my proxy server later on, which is working. For one host, however, I need to remove the iptables mark (i.e. the packets will not be redirected.) I tried the following:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.0.47 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

I have also tried (attempting to rewrite the mark to a different number):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.0.47 --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

However none of them are working. Is there a `--remove-mark`? I couldn't find anything on Google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/459477/how-to-remove-a-mark-set-by-iptables

Comment: I found that question @AbsoluteƵERØ however I'm don't think that they mean the same thing as my question - the first answer talks about deleting the rule which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the following:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! -s 192.168.0.47 --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

To mark it so it doesn't mark the host in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

When using the MARK target, the mark is a added as a bitmask.  If you check in the documentation, there's an optional [/mask] for the mark.

So use "--set-mark 0/2" to remove 2.